# Javascript: grab elements on a newly generated page?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript to add an event to my google calendar and go back to the main calendar page,THIS IS ALL DONE IN THE CONSOLE ON THE GOOGLE CALENDAR PAGE. So far I'm using this

```
javascript: 
var eventCheckList = document.getElementsByClassName("evt-lk"); 
for (var i = 0; i < 1 (1 just to test the code); i++) 
{
    eventCheckList[i].click();
    var possibleReturn = document.getElementsByClassName("goog-imageless-button"); 
    for (var j = 0; j < possibleReturn.length; j++)
    {
        var node = possibleReturn[j]; console.log(node.getAttribute("title"));
        if (node.getAttribute("title")=="Back to calendar"){
            console.log("Clicking");
            node.click(); break;
        }
    }
};
```

So it's grabbing an event, clicking on it, and then clicking the back button, just to test things out. So when I'm on the main calendar page and execute the script, it'll go to the event details, however, when it tries to find the back button, it doesn't find anything. When I again run the same script on the event details page, it does find the back button, clicks it, and I'm back on the main calendar page. Any reason why I can't run this from the main calendar page and click into all the events and back?

TLDR: issue seems to be that javascript can't find the DOM elements on the new page, however, when I run the code anew, it's able to find them

Comment: I need more code. Try to recreate it in jsFiddle

Comment: It's actually done in the console in the google calendar page, so if you just go to your calendar app, and run the javascript, you should see the behavior I'm seeing!